# NSThread calling threading delegate function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using a framework to get information from the network. The problem is the function I'm using to get the information is threaded (ie. it gives information through a didFinish selector, not the actual function as the return value).

I want to create a separate NSThread that uses this threaded function. The problem is if I detach a thread, it won't wait for the information from this threaded function (and it doesn't know when the information is sent back).

Is there a way to fix this situation? In a nutshell, I want to turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read up on [NSRunLoop](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW5)

I think the basic approach will be something like this:

- In your detached thread main body

  - set yourself as a custom input source to the runloop
  - while your state is not done, run the runloop
- In `didFinish:`

  - set some state that says you're done
  - tell the runloop that the input source (yourself) fired